# How to apply different functions with different argument types to calculate results on a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a script that receives and input and generates and ouput based on the input.

There are two different inputs:

1. Input with data
2. Input with name of variable, function to apply to calculate that variable and a list of arguments to use on the variable. The arguments are the name of the columns on the data input.

Here is an example of the input data

```r
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
values <- "END_DATE,    EAD_1, EAD_2, EAD_3, W, P1, P2, P3
            31/12/2019,  1,     3,      5,  0.2,  0,  0, 0
            31/12/2019,  7,     11,     13, 0.2,  0,  0, 0
            31/01/2020,  15,    17,     19, 0.3,  0,  0, 0
            31/01/2020,  23,    29,     31, 0.4,  0,  0, 0
            31/03/2020,  37,    41,     43, 0.5,  0,  0, 0
"
dt_values <- fread(values, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

This is an example of the input that has the reference to a variable and the function to apply (I have simplified the example so it can be reproducible)

```r
operations <- " RES, FUNCTION,   VAR1,  VAR2,  VAR3  
                 P1, polinom_f, EAD_1, EAD_1,  W
                 P2, polinom_d, EAD_1, EAD_2,  P1
                 P3, polinom_f, P2,    EAD_2,  P2
"
dt_operations <- data.table(fread(operations, sep= ",", header = TRUE))
```

Then I define the functions:

```r
polinom_f_def <- function(x, y, w ) {  

  return( x * w + y * w)
}
polinom_d_def <- function(x, y, w){
  return (( x * w + y * w) / w )
}

my_predefined_functions <- c(
  polinom_f = polinom_f_def,
  polinom_d = polinom_d_def
)
```

The only way I have found to do this is like this.

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(dt_operations)){
  # print(i)
  row <-   dt_operations[i, ]

  dt_values[, row[, RES] := my_predefined_functions[[row[, FUNCTION]]](get(row[, VAR1]), get(row[, VAR2]), get(row[, VAR3]) ) ]

}
```

How can I change my code to use `map`?

The expected output is:

```r
dt_values
     END_DATE EAD_1 EAD_2 EAD_3   W   P1 P2   P3
1: 31/12/2019     1     3     5 0.2  0.4  4   28
2: 31/12/2019     7    11    13 0.2  2.8 18  522
3: 31/01/2020    15    17    19 0.3  9.0 32 1568
4: 31/01/2020    23    29    31 0.4 18.4 52 4212
5: 31/03/2020    37    41    43 0.5 37.0 78 9282
```

Comment: I updated the code. It should work.

Comment: you can prob use `mapply` but it might not be safe to be so open with your codes. e.g. one can wipe out everything on your disk with the appropriate RES, FUNCTION, VAR...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
invisible(dt_operations[, {
    dt_values[, (RES) := as.numeric(mapply(function(x, y, w) match.fun(FUNCTION)(x, y, w), 
        get(VAR1), get(VAR2), get(VAR3)))]
    NULL
}, 1L:nrow(dt_operations)])
dt_values[]
```

output:

```
     END_DATE EAD_1 EAD_2 EAD_3   W   P1 P2   P3
1: 31/12/2019     1     3     5 0.2  0.4  4   28
2: 31/12/2019     7    11    13 0.2  2.8 18  522
3: 31/01/2020    15    17    19 0.3  9.0 32 1568
4: 31/01/2020    23    29    31 0.4 18.4 52 4212
5: 31/03/2020    37    41    43 0.5 37.0 78 9282
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt_values  <- fread("END_DATE,    EAD_1, EAD_2, EAD_3, W, P1, P2, P3
31/12/2019,  1,     3,      5,  0.2,  0,  0, 0
31/12/2019,  7,     11,     13, 0.2,  0,  0, 0
31/01/2020,  15,    17,     19, 0.3,  0,  0, 0
31/01/2020,  23,    29,     31, 0.4,  0,  0, 0
31/03/2020,  37,    41,     43, 0.5,  0,  0, 0")

dt_operations <- fread(" RES, FUNCTION,   VAR1,  VAR2,  VAR3  
P1, polinom_f, EAD_1, EAD_1,  W
P2, polinom_d, EAD_1, EAD_2,  P1
P3, polinom_f, P2,    EAD_2,  P2")

polinom_f <- function(x, y, w ) {  
    x * w + y * w
}

polinom_d <- function(x, y, w){     
    (x * w + y * w) / w 
}

#convert to double to prevent class mismatch later
dt_values[, paste0("P", 1:3) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=paste0("P", 1L:3L)]
```

p.s.:Be careful with exposing the code this way as you might accidentally run some malicious code

Answer (score 2):

The difficult part of the code is that it is recursive. That is, the second operation depends on the result of the first operation. That to me suggests that a classic loop would be most appropriate.

```
# as noted by @chinsoon12 regarding class mismatch
dt_values[, paste0("P", 1:3) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=paste0("P", 1L:3L)]

# extract vectors so we are not extracting during loop
res <- dt_operations[['RES']]
fx <- dt_operations[['FUNCTION']]
var1 <- dt_operations[['VAR1']]
var2 <- dt_operations[['VAR2']]
var3 <- dt_operations[['VAR3']]

for (i in seq_len(nrow(dt_operations))) {
  dt_values[, (res[i]) := do.call(fx[i], unname(.SD)), .SDcols = c(var1[i], var2[i], var3[i])]
}
dt_values[]

     END_DATE EAD_1 EAD_2 EAD_3     W    P1    P2    P3
       <char> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1: 31/12/2019     1     3     5   0.2   0.4     4    28
2: 31/12/2019     7    11    13   0.2   2.8    18   522
3: 31/01/2020    15    17    19   0.3   9.0    32  1568
4: 31/01/2020    23    29    31   0.4  18.4    52  4212
5: 31/03/2020    37    41    43   0.5  37.0    78  9282
```

A second way is to use `data.table`'s update-by-reference. The side effect is that during a `by` operation, each subsequent grouping will have access to whatever was calculated it previous groupings. The good news is that you can use `Map` (or `map`). The bad news is that you will be expanding the needed memory amount because the results are duplicated.

Hat tip to @chinsoon12 as this is derivative of their post. But, it is enlightening to see the actual printout:

```
dt_operations[,
              dt_values[,
                        (RES) := Map(function(cl, v1, v2, v3) do.call(cl, unname(.SD[, c(v1, v2, v3), with = FALSE])),
                                     FUNCTION, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3)
                        ]
              , by = seq_len(nrow(dt_operations))]

    seq_len   END_DATE EAD_1 EAD_2 EAD_3     W    P1    P2    P3
      <int>     <char> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num> <num>
 1:       1 31/12/2019     1     3     5   0.2   0.4     0     0
 2:       1 31/12/2019     7    11    13   0.2   2.8     0     0
 3:       1 31/01/2020    15    17    19   0.3   9.0     0     0
 4:       1 31/01/2020    23    29    31   0.4  18.4     0     0
 5:       1 31/03/2020    37    41    43   0.5  37.0     0     0
 6:       2 31/12/2019     1     3     5   0.2   0.4     4     0
 7:       2 31/12/2019     7    11    13   0.2   2.8    18     0
 8:       2 31/01/2020    15    17    19   0.3   9.0    32     0
 9:       2 31/01/2020    23    29    31   0.4  18.4    52     0
10:       2 31/03/2020    37    41    43   0.5  37.0    78     0
11:       3 31/12/2019     1     3     5   0.2   0.4     4    28
12:       3 31/12/2019     7    11    13   0.2   2.8    18   522
13:       3 31/01/2020    15    17    19   0.3   9.0    32  1568
14:       3 31/01/2020    23    29    31   0.4  18.4    52  4212
15:       3 31/03/2020    37    41    43   0.5  37.0    78  9282
```